# separating line read from file by colon in a loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to seperate the ip and port using a bash script. Below is what I have

my proxies.txt file

```
48.54.87.45:1000
48.54.87.45:1001
48.54.87.45:1002
```

My bash script

```
#!/bin/sh
input="proxies.txt"
while IFS= read -r var
do
  echo "$var"
  IFS=':' read proxy port <<< "$var"
  echo "$proxy"
  echo "$port"
  echo "---------------"
done < "$input"
```

But I get the following error

Syntax error: redirection unexpected

I have tested the loop and it does read the file one by one. It's the `IFS` line which is giving the error.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Make sure your shell is bash, not `/bin/sh`.

Comment: And btw, make it `while IFS=: read -r proxy port _` and you'll only need the one `read`. Or if you *are* going to do a full-line `read`, it's cheaper in terms of performance to do `proxy=${var%%:*}` and `port=${port#*:}`

Answer (score 1):

`<<<` is bash-only syntax. If you try to use it in a script run with `/bin/sh` (with either a `#!/bin/sh` shebang or run with `sh scriptname`), it will cause this error.

Start your script with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, or another shebang that *actually invokes bash*.

Comment: I already have that. I will edit my question

Comment: You edited the question to show `/bin/sh`. `sh` is the wrong shell. `bash` is the right one.